# Facebook Scopes for ALL photos in Graph API v2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, php-5.4

This is more of a generic question: which combination of scope permissions and endpoints in V2.0 of the Graph API allows an app to access every photo that I either uploaded or that I was tagged in?

In other apps I've seen "this app will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list, email address, photos and videos and your friends' photos and videos."
I only know of user_photos and user_videos, which when I use only returns 60% of the photos that I see when I'm logged into my personal Facebook account.

In browsing these lists in graph explorer, it's not clear which permissions are responsible for "your friends' photos and videos.
[image: User Data Permissions]
[image: Extended Permissions]

Answer (score 0):

Found this bug report on Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/701749743226238/